# Installing Hugs 98 on macOS sierra

Tags: haskell, installation, macos-sierra, hugs

I am having trouble installing Hugs 98  on macOS Sierra. I have followed the instructions here (http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/154/HugsMacInstall.html) which tell me to install macports then run sudo port install hugs98. Unfortunately, this results in the following error message :

Error: Processing of port hugs98 failed

Does anyone know if installing HUGS on macOS sierra is going to be possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you required to use Hugs for something? If not, you should use GHC. GHC updates regularly, while the latest release of Hugs is 10 years old.

Comment: If you're working with course material designed around Hugs, you may want to use GHC version 7.8. Changes since then could confuse you somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside other respondents' caveats about the wisdom of using hugs at all, you can [get a version of Hugs that works splendidly on the current (10.12.3) version of Sierra here](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/installing-hugs-98-haskell/).

The instructions work as stated, and building should take between 5 and 10 minutes.